# Broken connection

Tags: tcp, centos, firewall

I have a long running PHP script runned on centos 7 , that have some long TCP connection to other machine

When I disable firewall in centos everything works well , But when I enable firewall ,firstly everything is good but after hours , I see some error like

- Broken Pipe
- Connection timed out

Why? I have `heartbeat` mechanism in script , I try both heartbeat = 15 and 60

Why firewall affect my long TCP connections? Why it close my connection after hours?

Comment: What kind of firewall? Does it happen at a specific time? Do you know if the heartbeat packets get through the firewall?

Comment: I am using `firewalld` and I know heartbeat packets get through the firewall